# react native ios deeplinking URL scheme domain

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I am trying to integrate deeplinking in react-native project for ios platform. However in the `URL scheme` under `Item 0` i want to specify domain name as well.
For e.g: if i have declared `testapp` as the value for `Item 0` the app opens if the url if `testapp://abc`. However I want the app to open when the link is `https://testapp/abc`.
I have added the Universal Links code in my AppDelegate.m file but still the safari browser goes to the link instead of opening the app.

[This is my URL types in Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQP6H.png)